# Jetty file upload via multipart request directly farward file to FileInputStream

Tags: java, upload, jetty, multipart

I am currently implementing a file upload service in java using jetty as my servelet container. I am facing an issue I want to get fixed.
I have an endpoint for the file upload which is a post endpoint which takes multipart form data.
This works fine for small files but gives me a headache when a user uploads a big file. If I am not wrong then Jetty Buffers the uploaded file before forwarding it to my `FileInputStream`.
By this I mean that it fills its internal buffer first and then writes it to the `FileInputStream`. Is there a way to stop this and tweak jetty that it directly relays the data to the `FileInputStream` before buffering it?
I already tried to wrap the input stream into a buffered one but still, Jetty first consumes the file, buffers it and then writes it to the `InputStream`.
After some research, I saw a comment suggesting to use put instead and then access the raw data to achieve this direct forwarding. But I was wondering if there is another maybe even better way.

Regards Artur

Answer (score 0):

When working with large files on `multipart/form-data` make sure you are using the most recent RFC7578 as it's the most performant.

```java
Server server = new Server();

HttpConfiguration httpConfig = new HttpConfiguration();
httpConfig.setMultiPartFormDataCompliance(MultiPartFormDataCompliance.RFC7578);
ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server, 
    new HttpConnectionFactory(httpConfig));
server.addConnector(connector)
```

Next, when you are using the `HttpServletRequest.getPart(String)` method, you should know that Jetty internally has to extract the contents of the `multipart/form-data` to be accessible by both the `.getPart()` and `.getParameter()` methods.

Accessing large files this way is actually a unit test in Jetty itself.

See: [HugeResourceTest.java](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.x/jetty-webapp/src/test/java/org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/HugeResourceTest.java)

Comment: This is handy, but still doesn't answer the OP's question of not caching the entire body of the request before being able to access any of the "part". Is there a mechanism where each "part" is available as soon as it's received and can therefore be "consumed" by the handler immediately instead of waiting for all the parts to arrive before `getParts()` returns.

Comment: The APIs for `getParts()` and `getPart(String name)` are dependent on reading the entire request body content before returning from those API calls.  You can configure it to cache to disk or memory, but it still needs to read it as even a simple `.getPart("filename")` can fail if that segment name is provided more than once, or not at all.

Comment: Gotcha! Makes sense. My personal use case is to upload a large file (~500MB) to a jetty instance running on a small server with limited RAM. I guess I could enable caching the parts to disk to help with memory pressure? How would one enable that?

Comment: @notthetup use either the `@MultipartConfig` annotation or the `<multipart-config>` web descriptor (`WEB-INF/web.xml`), they have the configurations you are looking for.